# Is it ok to stand atop my central A/C unit to install a missing soffit vent?

Tags: hvac

Unless I go on top of the roof, it's the only to get to it without a step ladder. I don't know if the covers on these things are meant to stand the weight of a 250lb guy.  Aside from falling and breaking my arse, could I do serious damage to the unit itself?

Answer (score 1):

The condenser is usually made of simple sheet metal. So no, I would not recommend standing on it. You could instead use 2 ladders on either side with a platform between them.

Comment: English Russia website has several tragically humorous pictures of the results, not a good idea to destroy your AC and nearly do yourself in.